# mat-sidenav column not working, fxLayout="column"

Tags: angular

I've added a mat-sidenav navigation to my site and set it to be a column, but it's not working.
this is my HTML code:

```
<div> 
  <mat-toolbar style="height: 7vh; color: honeydew; background-color:rgb(43, 44, 44); position: relative;" lang="en" dir="ltr" class="mat-elevation-z8" >
    <br>
      <button [routerLink]="['']" routerLinkActive="active"  style="background-color: rgb(43, 44, 44);">
        <span><mat-icon>home</mat-icon></span>
      </button>
      <div class="spacerleft"></div>
      <h4>MaxProfit.TEB</h4>
      <div class="spacerleft"></div>
    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" dir="rtl">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>

    <span class="spacer"></span>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <mat-sidenav-container fxFlexFill class="example-container" style="color: honeydew; background-color:rgb(43, 44, 44); min-height: 93vh !important" lang="en" dir="rtl"> 
    <mat-sidenav color="honeydew" style="background-color: rgb(43, 44, 44); color: honeydew;" #sidenav mode="over"  opened="false" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
      <div fxLayout="column">
        <a (click)="sidenav.toggle()" mat-button routerLink="/signup"><mat-icon>input</mat-icon>הרשמה</a>
        <a (click)="sidenav.toggle()" mat-button routerLink="/login"><mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>התחברות</a>
        <a (click)="sidenav.toggle()" mat-button routerLink="/guidelines"><mat-icon>check_circle_outline</mat-icon>תנאי שימוש</a>
        <a (click)="sidenav.toggle()" mat-button routerLink="/academy"><mat-icon>border_color</mat-icon>אקדמיה</a>
        <a (click)="sidenav.toggle()" mat-button routerLink="/meta-trader"><mat-icon>attach_money</mat-icon>MetaTrader4</a>
        <a (click)="sidenav.toggle()" mat-button routerLink="/journey"><mat-icon> directions_walk</mat-icon>Journry</a>
        <a (click)="sidenav.toggle()" mat-button routerLink="/reviews"><mat-icon>feedback</mat-icon>ביקורות</a>
        <a (click)="sidenav.toggle()" mat-button routerLink="/feedback"><mat-icon>message</mat-icon>משוב</a>
      </div>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill>
      <router-outlet class="routerstyle"></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

what I get on the site:
mobile

[image]

desktop[image]

Comment: first you have to define fxLayout="row" or fxLayout="column" in the parent div

Comment: @BiswajitNath in the first line of html code I've uploaded?